# How to apply a time windows of 1 second and moving forwards of 250 ms to a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I would like to build an array of dataframe portions where each portion is obtained by rolling a pandas dataframe with a time windows of one 1 seconds but sliding forwards every 250 millisecond.

DF:

```
time,                    ax,       ay,        az,       id
2018-01-24 13:43:58.700, 0.021973, 0.012283, -0.995468, 1
2018-01-24 13:43:58.711, 0.021072, 0.013779, -0.994308, 1
2018-01-24 13:43:58.721, 0.020157, 0.015717, -0.995575, 1
2018-01-24 13:43:58.733, 0.017883, 0.012756, -0.993927, 1
...
2018-01-24 13:43:59.700, 0.021194, 0.012161, -0.994705, 1
2018-01-24 13:43:59.712, 0.019638, 0.013718, -0.994019, 0
2018-01-24 13:43:59.721, 0.019440, 0.010803, -0.994476, 0
...
2018-01-24 13:44:00.700, 0.018112, 0.010849, -0.993073, 0
2018-01-24 13:44:00.712, 0.011154, 0.010849, -0.994644, 0
2018-01-24 13:44:00.721, 0.020340, 0.010040, -0.995804, 0
...
```

As output, I am expecting an array of dataframe portions as follows:

DF1 that starts 2018-01-24 13:43:58.700
DF1 that ends   2018-01-24 13:43:59.700

DF2 that starts 2018-01-24 13:43:58.950
DF2 that ends   2018-01-24 13:43:59.950

etc..

My attempt is to apply the following line of codes:

```
df["ephoc_as_datatime"] = pd.to_datetime(df["ephoc_as_datatime"]) # Convert column type to be datetime
indexed_df = df.set_index(["ephoc_as_datatime"])                  # Create a datetime index
print(indexed_df.rolling(100))                                    # Then apply functions to rolling windows
```

How Can I say move forwards of 250ms?
How I can take each portion and put it in an array?

Any help would be very appreciated. 
Many Thanks in advance
Carlo

Comment: Can you explain your expected output a bit more, or post expected output?

Comment: maybe `indexed_df.rolling('250L')`

Comment: does it mean that you move forward of 250ms, right? how are you selecting a DF portion of 1 second?